# Transform and load a large CSV to multiple worksheets in one Excel file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, excel-2007, vba

#### Back Story:

NEW PROJECT FROM MANAGEMENT: I have been given a soft project from my boss to evaluate one of our current ETL plans to look for room for improvement in the process, and I am looking for guidance.

MOTIVE: Excel is currently being used and crashes quite often during the process due to file size.

TASK: Every month an analyst receives a large csv file from a survey vendor containing up to 750 columns (not all unique names) with over 15,000 rows to simply transform a large csv file into an excel file with seven worksheets broken up based on the column headings in the csv. Details of how it is broken up is below.

My question is one large csv being transformed into an edited excel file with multiple worksheets any easier or quicker using VB.NET and VS2010 or VBA for that matter, or would using Excel be the simplilest way to continue this process? I am an Expert Excel user but I am still very much a beginner to intermediate at coding in VBA, VB.NET or any other language.

---

#### Detailed Question:

I am open to using free or open source software, but I am most familiar with VB.NET and Excel and Excel-VBA. I have played around a bit coding a simple windows form application to load the csv into a datatable using similar [TextFieldParser code found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx). I have thought of loading it into an array or even a 2d array to more easily edit the column headings and find the duplicate column headings. The datatable option still leaves me with more questions than answers because I need unique column headings and not sure if I should bother with a datatable if I'm going to just write an excel file right away.  I tried [CSVreader from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) won't work on files with duplicate header names. I feel as though I am having writers block as I am not sure which direction I should take handle such a process. Any input you can provide will be much appreciated, and I apologize if this question does not have a single and clear best answer, Thanks.

---

#### Current Analyst tasks using excel

The current analytical plan has said analyst to open the csv in excel, insert a row above row 1 and use a vlookup to replace the 'New' column names with the 'Old' column names based on a simple two column lookup table on a separate worksheet. For example

```
New becomes Old
"org-name" becomes "org_name" or 
"item_1_Vendor" becomes "item_1" or
"date-created_Survey" becomes "date_created"
etc...checking all sent "New" columns against the list of all possible 750 columns.
```

Then they paste values of the first row and then delete the 2nd row which contained the New headings we want to change.

Then the analyst has to fix the primary key on the file which is called "sid".
The Survey ID field (sid) should have a number for each row of the data file.  Sometimes the sid shows up under the sid_HCAHPS or the sid_CGCAHPS fields instead.
The analyst would insert a column next to the "sid" field and put a formula in it like this, for example:
`=IF(BE2<>"",BE2,IF(RD2<>"",RD2,IF(UH2<>"",UH2,"")))`
Actual cell references would change but in the example excel formula,

```
"sid"=Range("BE2")
"sid_HCAHPS"=Range("RD2")
"sid_CGCAHPS"=Range("UH2")
```

Once the newly created primary key column is made and filled without blanks, we can delete the original "sid" column.

The next step is to check the columns because there may be a redundant HCAHPS section of columns (due to a second survey being sent and then returned- coded as Wave 2), delete second set of columns "sid_HCAHPS" through "language"

Next is the largest alteration because we have setup a system where we send this information to our database admins in the form of a seven worksheet excel file to be loaded by an MS Access Query that creates a table from each sheet that gets loaded into our proprietary business intelligence software. All Done!!

---

Comment: Sounds to me like this CSV file really should be loaded into an Access table FIRST (since that's a much better tool for handling large amounts of data like this), then run various queries (and possibly Access VBA if needed) in there to split it into the seven tables. 
If that's not possible for some reason, then Excel VBA should certainly be able to do the job. I can't speak for VB.NET, I've never used that with Excel work.

Comment: The problem with using access is the limit of 256 columns per table. So the file can't be loaded into a table until it is cut up.

Comment: I see, I didn't know Access had that limitation. Well I think VBA can automate the steps you described above and is probably easier to use than VB.NET since VBA would work directly in Excel which is where all the work seems to take place.

Comment: actually, 15000 * 750 = 11.3M cells. Excel can handle this many with absolutely no problems. If any code is running very slowly or crashing it is because it is probably not very well written. Every Range operation has an overhead, so DO NOT LOOP THROUGH CELLS etc. With this many rows and columns, try not to work on a worksheet (Insert columns etc), but instead work on the data in an array or collection in memory, outputting the final product to the worksheets in a single operation, or at the very least working on columns at once, not cells, through RangeOfCells.Value/Formula = etc.

Comment: I've used Chip Pearson's `ImportBigTextFile` routine on a few occasions in the past. This allows you to import enormous files in to Excel.   http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ImportBigFiles.htm

Comment: @Cor_Blimey excel runs into problems when the analyst does more and more to the file thus fillung up the Undo history. It has been beneficial to us to make a change or two, save the file, close excel, then open it all back up thus dumping the undo memory and improving performance. This is what I would like to eliminate. Thanks for your suggestions as well.

Comment: @DavidZemens `ImportBigTextFile` looks very interesting. I will take a look at it thanks.

Comment: @Scheballs, I feel your pain - I literally bang my head on my desk sometimes when having to work with stupid 200MB excel files. Try using the .xlsb format as it is substantially faster opening/saving. The process you outline above does sound very well suited for automating (either in VBA or a .NET language (I like C#)). As each row is effectively processed independently and uniformly (after the header) you can work on a file stream, processing the data and immediately pumping it to the output file. This is suitable for an arbitrarily large file :-)

Comment: @Scheballs, alternatively, you could use Access. A saved import means it would be a one-click import, then a few queries (that would of course be reusable going forwards) could be written that apply the necessary transformations to result in the final table, which you then export to a flat file / excel, again which can be saved as a one-click export.

Answer (score 2):

Is your question, "can VB.net automate our current analyst tasks?" -If so, then yes.

You could use the streamreader class to get data from your csv
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

Then store it either in an array as you mentioned or use the *list class
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Once you've got all your data stored you'll need to automate excel, this is quite straight forward but here's a link to get you started with that as well: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982/en-gb

- With the list class you can create a list of custom objects using either classes or structures. eg.

We define a structure:

```
Structure rowOfData
    Public intPrimaryKey as Integer
    Public strIceCreamName as String
    Public decPrice as Decimal
End Structure
```

We can then create a rowOfData and add properties to it:

```
Dim iceCream1 as rowOfData
iceCream1.intPrimaryKey = 1
iceCream1.strIceCreamName = "Mr Whippy"
iceCream1.decPrice = 0.99
```

We create a list with:

```
Dim listOfIceCreams as New List(of rowOfData)
```

And add to it like this:

```
listOfIceCreams.Add(iceCream1)
listOfIceCreams.Add(iceCream2)
etc.
```

And access the members of the list like this:

```
listOfIceCreams(0).decPrice 'gives us the price of the ice Cream that was added to the list first.
```

There are also a lot of other useful methods that lists have which arrays don't. You could have a look through that msdn list class link to see if anything jumps out at you that you might need

Comment: Thanks for the link on automating excel, with as much searching as I have done I can't believe I haven't seen this already. The List class is interesting but what would be the main benefit to this over using an array?

Comment: i've updated my answer. Lists are more customisable which is why you might prefer them to hold and work with your data

Comment: having just seen that you've got 256 columns you might be better of using an array than a list :P